# setInterval in loop nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops

I know that there are other questions just like this but my code just doesnt seems to work.
Could you have a look at my code and tell me where i am wrong.

```
 var mysql = require('mysql');

var client = mysql.createClient({
  user: 'jed',
  password: 'jed8703',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'jedtest'
});

//var query = client.query(
//  'INSERT INTO testtable '+
//  'SET testid = ?, name = ?, value = ?',
//  [1, 'test', 'test']
//);


client.query(
  'SELECT * FROM testtable',
  function selectCb(err, results, fields) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    console.log(results[0].Name);
    for(var i in results)
        {
            (function(y)
            {
                setInterval(function() {
                  console.log(results[y].Name + 'value:' + results[y].Value );
                }, 5000 );
            })
        }
  }
);

client.end();
```

Comment: It does not seem to be good design to create `x` intervals which in addition will be executed all at the same time.

Comment: I think the answers so far are correct as to why it doesn't work, but why are you using `setInterval()` in the first place? (Alarm bells go off in my head whenever I see `setInterval()` called from inside a loop...)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't forget to invoke the function:

```
        (function(y)
        {
            setInterval(function() {
              console.log(results[y].Name + 'value:' + results[y].Value );
            }, 5000 );
        })(i); // <------- Added (i);
```

Note that your delay may not behave as expected. Currently, you're executing all methods after 5 seconds. Create a queue if you want to have a delay of 5 seconds between each call.

Answer (score 2):

You are not fullfilling `y` variable, try replacing:

```
   (function(y)
   {
      setInterval(function() {
        console.log(results[y].Name + 'value:' + results[y].Value );
      }, 5000 );
   })
```

With:

```
   (function(y)
   {
      setInterval(function() {
        console.log(results[y].Name + 'value:' + results[y].Value );
      }, 5000 );
   })(i); // <------------------
```